# Can an indexed page never be returned to any search query?

Tags: google-index

Assuming Google finds a website with 100 pages and decides to index 80 pages.

Does it perform further filtering on these pages or will start matching user queries with all the 80 indexed pages (on the long run)?

In other words, is it possible for an indexed page to never be returned to user search queries?

Let's assume there is no site wide penalty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible for an indexed page to never be returned to user search queries?

"Never" is a pretty broad word in this case.  At some point, an indexed page will be returned to a given query.  The more words in the query that match words or phrases on the page, the more likely it will be shown in a result.  If someone targets your domain using the site: command in Google, the chances go up dramatically that a page will be returned.

To extend the hypothetical to the maximum silliness, let us assume you have a page with nothing but

```
dfvldfmvl sfjvnsafgnva weaugnaoweiun
```

as the content.  This could possibly be a page that Google would never return as a result because unless the user is searching by spastically banging their head into the keyboard the odds on entering a query that would match one of the above strings [is](https://www.google.com/search?q=dfvldfmvl) [pretty](https://www.google.com/search?q=sfjvnsafgnv) [remote](https://www.google.com/search?q=weaugnaoweiun). However, don't discount Google's "Did you mean?" search result to return garbage against garbage and thus somehow return a page with the above text in response to a random character search for wholly different characters.

If you are worried about a page getting indexed that shouldn't be, a simple adjustment to your robots.txt will take care of that.  If you are concerned that a page should be coming up in response to certain terms but isn't, that's a whole other thing and likely means your SEO, isn't.